# RVM cannot load such file -- win32/resolv (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin, rvm, resolv

I used RVM to install ruby 2.2.3. It successfully installed, but when I run gem install rails (or any gem for that matter), it gives me this error:

```
$ gem install rails
/home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- win32/resolv (LoadError)
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:964:in `default_config_hash'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:982:in `block in lazy_initialize'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:975:in `synchronize'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:975:in `lazy_initialize'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:357:in `block in lazy_initialize'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:355:in `synchronize'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:355:in `lazy_initialize'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:515:in `fetch_resource'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:509:in `each_resource'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb:490:in `getresource'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:92:in `api_endpoint'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:46:in `api_uri'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source.rb:85:in `dependency_resolver_set'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:23:in `block in pick_sets'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/source_list.rb:97:in `each_source'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:22:in `pick_sets'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/best_set.rb:28:in `find_all'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:151:in `find_all'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:54:in `add_always_install'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:473:in `resolve_dependencies'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:238:in `install_gem'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:299:in `block in install_gems'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `each'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:295:in `install_gems'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:202:in `execute'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:307:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:168:in `process_args'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:138:in `run'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:54:in `run'
        from /home/laury/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Windows 10 Pro, Cygwin, rvm 1.27.0. There was an older open issue on RVM's github (https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3519) that looks pretty similar to what I'm getting, but an answer was never found.

Comment: When I compare it to what RailsInstaller does, I notice that it's missing a lot of standard libraries like win32 and fiddle. Was there something I was supposed to do beyond rvm install 2.2.3 and rvm use 2.2.3?

Comment: Stupid question: why don't you use the ruby coming as cygwin package (version 2.2.4-1) ?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is to make sure you install `libffi-devel` also, and then reinstall ruby. That way all the needed gems like fiddle/win32 will be properly be installed.

I just followed the same process and it fixed it for me on an even newer Ruby  version: 2.3.1